# Is there a way to not use global variables in my code?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am relatively new to Python so please bear with the inefficiency of my code. This is one of my first Tkinter applications and it is quite a simple one. It is a code guessing game where the user tries to guess a randomly generated 4 digit code. The code currently prints the randomly generated number so that it is easier to see if the code is working. But is there a way to not use global variables in this code. Also, it would be helpful if I was told how to make my code efficient. Thanks in advance. Code:

```
import random
import tkinter as tk

number_of_tries = 0


def tries():
    global number_of_tries
    number_of_tries += 1
    comment.configure(state="normal")
    comment.delete(0, "end")
    comment.insert(0, "Not quite! Keep trying!")
    comment.configure(state="disabled")
    if str(guess) == str(random_number):
        comment.configure(state="normal")
        comment.delete(0, "end")
        comment.insert(0, "You guessed it in " + str(number_of_tries) + " tries!")
        comment.configure(state="disabled")
        guess_entry.configure(state="disabled")
        go.configure(state="disabled")


def character_check():
    global guess
    guess = guess_entry.get()
    if len(guess) != 4:
        comment.configure(state="normal")
        comment.delete(0, "end")
        comment.insert(0, "Guess must be 4 digits! ")
        comment.configure(state="disabled")
    else:
        for char in guess:
            if char.isalpha():
                comment.configure(state="normal")
                comment.delete(0, "end")
                comment.insert(0, "Guess must only include integers! ")
                comment.configure(state="disabled")
            else:
                digit_check()


def digit_check():
    global guess
    guess = guess_entry.get()

    for i in range(0, 4):
        if str(guess)[i] == str(random_number)[i]:
            digits[i] = str(guess)[i]
            digit_display.configure(state="normal")
            digit_display.delete(0, "end")
            digit_display.insert(0, digits)
            digit_display.configure(state="disabled")
        elif str(guess)[i] != str(random_number)[i]:
            digits[i] = "?"
            digit_display.configure(state="normal")
            digit_display.delete(0, "end")
            digit_display.insert(0, digits)
            digit_display.configure(state="disabled")


def initialise():
    global number_of_tries, digits
    global random_number
    digits = ["?"] * 4
    random_number = random.randrange(1000, 9999)
    number_of_tries = 0
    digit_display.configure(state="normal")
    comment.configure(state="normal")

    digit_display.delete(0, "end")
    digit_display.insert(0, digits)
    comment.delete(0, "end")
    comment.insert(0, "Good luck!")

    digit_display.configure(state="disabled")
    comment.configure(state="disabled")
    guess_entry.configure(state="normal")
    go.configure(state="normal")
    print(random_number)


screen = tk.Tk()
screen.geometry("400x400")
screen.title("Code Crunchers")

heading = tk.Label(text="Welcome to Code Crunchers!", font="Montserrat 15")
heading.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, anchor="center")

instruction_1 = tk.Label(text="Enter your guess below: ", font="Montserrat 10")
instruction_1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor="center")

guess_entry = tk.Entry(screen, width=4)
guess_entry.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, anchor="center")

go = tk.Button(text="Go", font="Montserrat 10", command=lambda: [character_check(), tries()])
go.place(relx=0.6, rely=0.27, anchor="center")

instruction_2 = tk.Label(text="Digits correct: ", font="Montserrat 10")
instruction_2.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.35, anchor="center")

digit_display = tk.Entry(screen, width=10)
digit_display.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.4, anchor="center")

comment = tk.Entry(screen, width=40)
comment.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.45, anchor="center")

restart = tk.Button(text="Restart", font="Montserrat 10", command=lambda: initialise())
restart.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.55, anchor="center")

initialise()

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Put the code inside a class, then you can use instance variables instead of global variables.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is simply display the number of tries to the user and then read from that object to see the amount of tries. If you do not want to display it to the user you can always hide it so it does not display. If you do not want to have it on your GUI at all you should then pass this variable around as arguments in your functions.